# How to Pass Matrix Array to Java Method arguments List Integer variable error:error:No method 'list_method' with matching signature found for class?

Tags: java, matlab, matlab-guide

On Mat-lab Part Side.

```
 array = [2,1,2,3,1,3,33,4]; % various matrix  1-by-8 dimension 
 import edu.lipreading.*;
 training = MainMethod;//Java Class
 training.list_method(array);
```

On java Code :

```
 public void list_method(List<Integer> points){
    Sample sample = new Sample();
     sample.getMatrix().add(points); //here Expected Points variable  result like [2,1,2,3,1,3,33,4]
 }
```

I have got `Error:No method 'list_method' with matching signature found for class`
please let me know where I have made a mistake ?

Answer (score 0):

Check if the class is loaded by a different class loader.
An excellent explanation of how classloaders work is given the the tutorial which can be downloaded [here](http://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/rebel-labs-tutorial-do-you-really-get-classloaders/)

Comment: Thank's for reply me.If I have tried like working  java method  argument integer  like On Java Part : public void list_method(int  a){ } On Mat-lab Part : import lipreading.*;
 training = Main-method;
 training.list_method(100); so i have passed integer variable from mat-lab to java method arguments .So i would like to pass matrix=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8] %1-by-8 matrix to Java Method List<Integer>Points